# 一定時間アイドル状態になっているSpringを自動停止させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-spring

最近PCの空きメモリが少なくなっているなあと思ったら、複数のRailsアプリでSpringが起動しっぱなしになっていることに気がつきました。（Macのアクティビティモニタで確認しました）

`spring stop` してやるとプロセスが停止してメモリが解放されるのですが、いろんなRailsアプリを行き来していると毎回忘れずに stop させるというのも現実的ではありません。

たとえば、Powのように一定時間アイドル状態になっていると自動的にSpringを停止できたりすれば、不要なメモリの消費を抑えられると思います。

何らかの形で起動しっぱなしのSpringを止めたいのですが何かいい方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

Spring によって起動する常駐プロセスに対して、一定時間が経過したらメインスレッドを停止する (== 常駐プロセスを `exit` させる) タイマーを仕込むのはどうでしょう。

以下のコードを手元で試したところ動作しました。これを `~/.spring.rb` か `config/spring.rb` に書いておきます。 `sleep` のあたりは使いやすいように変更してみてください。

```
Thread.new do
  sleep ENV.fetch('SPRING_AUTOSTOP', 1.day).to_i
  Thread.main.exit
end
```

(Rails 4.1.7 Spring 1.1.3)

参考: https://github.com/rails/spring#running-code-before-forking

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。なるほど、確かに自動停止はできそうですね。ただ、運が悪いとテストの実行中とかに突然停止することもありそうです。。。